# In slow_log tables, sql_text column showing "throttle: index not used' warning(s) suppressed" instead of exact query

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, performance, slow-log

I'm trying to find the slow running queries from slow_log table (as I don't have direct access to server to check slow log file). In sql_text column instead of query it is showing "throttle: index not used' warning(s) suppressed". Could someone help me how to find the slow running query.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are using MySQL 5.5 ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you are not going to get those queries from `mysql.slow_log`. Why ?

There are two options evidently being used

- [log_queries_not_using_indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_queries_not_using_indexes)
- [log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes)

According to [MySQL Documentation (The Slow Query Log, Paragraph 9)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/slow-query-log.html)

> To include queries that do not use indexes for row lookups in the statements written to the slow query log, enable the log_queries_not_using_indexes system variable. When such queries are logged, the slow query log may grow quickly. It is possible to put a rate limit on these queries by setting the log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes system variable. By default, this variable is 0, which means there is no limit. Positive values impose a per-minute limit on logging of queries that do not use indexes. The first such query opens a 60-second window within which the server logs queries up to the given limit, then suppresses additional queries. If there are suppressed queries when the window ends, the server logs a summary that indicates how many there were and the aggregate time spent in them. The next 60-second window begins when the server logs the next query that does not use indexes.

What this shows is that your [log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes) is set so that SQL text is suppressed. You can verify this with

```
mysql> SELECT @@global.log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes;
```

Since it is a global dynamic variable, you must login as `root@localhost` and run

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes = 0;
```

This should expose new queries entering `mysql.slow_log`, but you will never see what those previous slow queries were.

You must run this

```
mysql> SELECT @@global.log_output;
```

If you see `FILE,TABLE` that means there is a text version of the slow query log. You will have to get your SysAdmin to get you the desired slow log info (Starbucks GiftCard might be required for this one. If the slow log file contains the same messages, take your Starbucks GitftCard back.)